# Which domain is correct for the function $f(x)=2\log(x-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(x)=2\log(x-3)$

Then

$$\text{ Dom}(f)=(3, \infty)$$

But by property of logarithm $$n\log b=\log(b^n)$$

we can write $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=\log(x^2-6x+9)$$ and now the domain is $\mathbb{R}-\{3\}$.

Can I know which is correct?

Comment: $n\log b=\log(b^n)$ only when $b\gt 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $f(x)=2\log(x-3)$ as you mentioned $\mathbb{D}_f=(3,\infty)$ whereas if $g(x)=\log(x-3)^2$  then $\mathbb{D}_g=\mathbb{R}-\{3\}$. Indeed $f\ne g$

**Note**

$f$ and $g$ are equal if and only if

- $\mathbb{D}_f=\mathbb{D}_g$
- For every $x\in D_f=D_g\quad,$ $f(x)=g(x)$